# How to make CRUD operations in Django without a page reload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying make [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations in Django without a page reload and also implement Django Form validation, like duplicate messages and error messages.

How can I do it?

Comment: With AJAX calls...

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) requests to conduct CRUD tasks in Django without having to reload the page. AJAX allows you to transmit and receive data from the server asynchronously without refreshing the entire page.

- Normally, create Django views to handle the crud to return the json response.
- Use jQuery in your Template to make AJAX requests
- By using jQuery the sub templates will render itself, once Successful AJAX Request is made.

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation explain only how to add data via jQuery Ajax, but it does not explain how to retrieve and update the data and also how to show a Django message via jQuery Ajax to HTML.

Comment: What documentation? Does it refer to [the ChatGPT answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76653263)? [Stack Overflow is ***not a forum***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). Stack Overflow is ***not a forum***. Stack Overflow is ***not a forum***. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer. [Stack Overflow is ***not a forum***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76653102/edit) (change your question) to add more information (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: (In this case, this ***doesn't*** apply (it is a case of thinking Stack Overflow is a forum. ***[Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)***): *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*)